# sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unterminated `s' command

Tags: command-line, sed, text

I have a text file that has many `groupid = []`. I wan't to edit the specific line which is 41, How can I do it?

My command: `sed -i "s/groupid = []/groupid = [ 2 ]/" rights.toml`

I have tried:

```
sed -i "s@groupid = []@groupid = [ 2 ]@" rights.toml
sed -i -e "s@groupid = []@groupid = [ 2 ]@g" "rights.toml"
sed -i "41 s/groupid = []/groupid = [ 2 ]/g" rights.toml
sed -i "41,s/groupid = []/groupid = [ 2 ]/g" rights.toml
sed -i "41s/groupid = []/groupid = [ 2 ]/g" rights.toml
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your sed command

```
s/groupid = []/groupid = [ 2 ]/
```

is that `[` and `]` are special characters on the LHS of a substitute command, so it's interpreting

```
]/groupid = [ 2
```

as a set of characters to match after `groupid =` . Since that "eats" the first `/`, your command looks like `s/pattern/` instead of `s/pattern/replacement`.

At a minimum, you need to escape the opening `[` to make it literal - I'd probably escape the closing `]` as well to make the intent clear:

```
sed "s/groupid = \[\]/groupid = [ 2 ]/" rights.toml
```

You can add an address to specify a particular line

```
sed "41s/groupid = \[\]/groupid = [ 2 ]/" rights.toml
```

however your file doesn't appear to have a `groupid` on line 41. As an aside, I'd recommend using `'   '` single quotes rather than double quotes around sed expressions *unless* you explicitly need to perform shell expansions within them.

***HOWEVER** you should really consider using a TOML aware tool rather than sed if your text is `TOML`.* For example, using [yq: Command-line YAML/XML/TOML processor - jq wrapper for YAML, XML, TOML documents](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq)
in TOML mode:

```
tomlq -t '.rule[0].groupid |= [2]' rights.toml
```

(again, it's not clear whether you want to modify `rule[0]` or `rule[1]` since line 41 doesn't appear to contain a `groupid`).